# Issue while loading external angular module to 'mainApp' module using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-amd

I recently started using RequireJS with AngularJS. I came across a plugin called AngularAMD, which makes it easier for Require and Angular to work together. I have the following config.

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "",    
    paths: {
        'angular': 'lib/js/angular.min',
        'angular-route': 'lib/js/angular-route.min',
        'angular-resource': 'lib/js/angular-resource.min',
        'angularAMD': 'lib/js/angularAMD.min',
        'jquery':'lib/js/jquery-1.11.3.min',
        'bootstrap':'lib/js/bootstrap.min',
        'httpAPIService' : 'httpAPIService',
        'angular-charts':'lib/js/angular-charts',
        'd3': 'lib/js/d3.min'
    },
    shim: { 'bootstrap':['jquery'], 'angular': ['jquery', 'bootstrap'], 'angularAMD': ['angular'], 'angular-route': ['angular'], 'angular-resource': ['angular'], 'angular-charts':['angular', 'd3'], 'httpAPIService': ['mainApp']},
    deps: ['mainApp']
});
```

Now in `mainApp.js` I have the following code:

```
define(['angularAMD', 'angular-route'], function (angularAMD) {

    var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

    mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/userAgreement", angularAMD.route({
            templateUrl: 'modules/agreement/views/eulaView.html', controller: 'eulaController',
            controllerUrl: 'modules/agreement/js/eulaController'
        }))
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/' 
        });
    });
    return angularAMD.bootstrap(mainApp);
});
```

Which works fine. But if I try to add `angular-charts` module to it. Like this:

```
define(['angularAMD', 'angular-route', 'angular-charts'], function (angularAMD) {

    var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute', 'angularCharts']);

    mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/userAgreement", angularAMD.route({
            templateUrl: 'modules/agreement/views/eulaView.html', controller: 'eulaController',
            controllerUrl: 'modules/agreement/js/eulaController'
        }))
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/' 
        });
    });
    return angularAMD.bootstrap(mainApp);
});
```

It' gives me `$injector:modulerr Module Error`. I am new to AMD concept. Please help.

Comment: Sure you spelled the module name correctly for the dependency array? Forget to load the module file?

Comment: Yes. According to the documentation I need to add `angularCharts`. And I checked in console module file is loading correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ngload` per [documentation](https://github.com/marcoslin/angularAMD#3rd-party-angularjs-modules)?

```
define(['angularAMD', 'angular-route', 'ngload!angular-charts'], function (angularAMD) {

...

})
```